# Getting rid of the margin at the end of the HTML file (attached)

Tags: html, svg, border

I want to convert an SVG file to a PDF file using a tool that we have at the office. The SVG file is the size of a A4 sheet and when we specify the page size in the arguments to the aforementioned tool, it will make a PDF file with that page size.

However, the input to the tool is HTML. The tool is using some version of Webkit.

So I have to embed the SVG file on an HTML file and input it to the tool. The actual embedding part is just fine. But I get a thin border at the end of each page which I don't know how to get rid of. That border also gets printed into the PDF file.

Note: There is a cunning trick. If I remove the !DOCTYPE HTML declaration at the top, it will go away. This might be a clue to some people but not to me. I want to keep it adhered to standards as this will be a module that will go into production.

The following are the sample HTML and SVG files I have created. I have colored the background of the HTML file as RED so that the border at the very end is noticeable.

First the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sample</title>
      <style>
         body
         {
            text-align:center;
            margin: 0px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="red">
    <object id="svg1" data="svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, the SVG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 595.32 841.32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <rect  
      x           ="0" 
      y           ="0" 
      width       ="595.32" 
      height      ="841.32" 
      fill        ="green" 
      stroke      ="green" 
      stroke-width="0.01"
   />
</svg>
```

Can anyone think of a way to get rid of this border? It might be a very simple trick, but I am not familiar with HTML so bear with me.

Thanks in advance.

-Anusha

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Tested on Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

```
  <style>
     body
     {
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0px;            
     }
     object
     { 
        display: block;
     } 
  </style>
```